# Can I have my Visual Studio 2015 point to SQL Server 2014 Instance?

Tags: visual-studio

I found that if you install it on a 64 bit PC, it will install SQL Server 2016 automatically, you will have a folder named 130 under C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server.

However, I don't have that folder on my PC as it is 32 bit, probably because there is no 32 bit version for SQL Server 2016. I only have a folder named 120, which corresponds to SQL Server 2014.

So the problem is my team mate created a solution(on a 64 bit computer with VS 2015) with 'Server based Database' in it, and handed that to me, I could not open it in my VS 2015, if I try to open the connection with the .mdf file, I will get an error saying:

> The database '...abc.MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 851.
>   This server supports version 782 and earlier. A downgrade path is not
>   supported. Could not open new database '...abc.MDF'. CREATE DATABASE
>   is aborted. An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file
>   ...abc.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified
>   file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

I have checked the setting Tools > Options > Database Tools > Data Connections > SQL Server Instance Name, since the instance name for both SQL Server 2014 and SQL Server 2016 is exactly the same((LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB), there is nothing I can do there.

In addition, I have also changed the compatibility level of the database to 120, on my teammate's PC of course. I still cannot open it.

My question is, can I make Visual Studio 2015 point to SQL Server 2014 instance?

If so, I can change that on the 64 bit computer, and the .mdf will be created with SQL Server 2014, so that I can open it with my own VS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that the raw database files are of a higher version than the version of SQL Server you have.

The compatibility is just for server features not the raw files.

Your team mate needs to use an earlier copy of SQL Server so the files he sends you are compatible.

Comment: How to do that, how to let his vs 2015 use SQL Server 2014? You see, we create Server based database in VS, everything is operated through VS.